# How to change selected value of a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I have to two comboboxes, based on the selection made in the first combobox the selected value of the second box should change.
Please find the code snippet below:

```
secondcombobox.setSelectedItem(firstcombobox.getSelectedItem());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use an [ActionListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29):

```
firstcombobox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

   void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       // sets the selected item of secondcombobox to be the value of firstcombobox
       // assuming secondcombobox contains such a value.
       secondcombobox.setSelectedItem(firstcombobox.getSelecteditem());
    }

});
```

Note scoping here is important.  You can either make `firstcombobox` and `secondcombobox` global or final, or you can use a slightly alternate form where you take those arguments as inputs to a constructor:

```
firstcombobox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(firstcombobox, secondcombobox){
   private JComboBox a;
   private JComboBox b;

   public ActionListner(JComboBox a, JComboBox b){
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
   }

   void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       // sets the selected item of a to be the value of b
       // assuming a contains such a value.
       b.setSelectedItem(a.getSelecteditem());
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code above will only work if the selected item in the first `JComboBox` also exists in the second `JComboBox`; In other words there exists an object in the second `ComboBoxModel` returns `true` when compared to the selected item from the first `JComboBox`.

If the selected item is not in the list, the method call **will have no effect**, which is suspect is what's happening in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If your two comboboxes share the same values, you should use the same model for them both. It would be cleaner than to use an ActionListener.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
combo1.setModel(model);
combo2.setModel(model);

//init your values in the combo here
```

Then, when you select an item in one of the comboBoxes, it will be selected in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Although your minimal question length makes your question cryptical, you will probably need:

```
firstcombobox.addActionListener() {
 // Do something with secondcombobox
}
```